# Guild Member Intent Missing, even though Guildmember Intent is activated Discord.NET

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am developing a Bot in which you can apply for Teams via a little Conversation in DM with the Bot, which Teamcaptains can than see and do whatever they want with it.

It was working fine until a certain point, when the users couldn't be downloaded anymore. I added All the Intents.
The Exception and Guild Intents are in the Attachment.

```
var channel = socketReaction.Channel as ITextChannel;
                var guild = channel.Guild;
                var guildUser = guild.GetUserAsync(userId).Result;
                if(guildUser == null)
                {
                    guild.DownloadUsersAsync().Wait();
                    guildUser = guild.GetUserAsync(userId).Result;
                }
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozXTq.png)

[Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZvs3.png)

Comment: You need to enable intents in code via the DiscordSocketConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627123/guild-member-intent-missing-even-though-guildmember-intent-is-activated-discord/70632119#comment124855525_70627123) that [Anu6is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11159372/anu6is) posted:

> You need to enable intents in code via the DiscordSocketConfig